# store javascript UTC date in mysql . php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, datetime

I have a json object which provides me the date in some kind of UTC format .

```
 "date":new Date(Date.UTC(2013,1,5,13,53,47))
```

How can store this in mysql and what kind of column type should I use ? I'm using PHP to retrieve / store the data

Answer (score 0):

Store this in the format of `YYYY-mm-dd`.  You can't quite do this in a single line, so try this:

```
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(/* your stuff */));
...
"date": d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate()
```

EDIT:

On the PHP side say that `date` is in `$_POST['date']`.  Use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']))` to get the value to store in MySQL.

Comment: would be possible to just convert it to a timestamp ?